# Is talisman melding random?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

When going through the caravan, you eventually unlock the ability to meld 3 talismans into one new one.

Does it matter what talismans I meld for the result? For example, if I meld 3 Crag+ talismans will it come out to be a better Crag+? The same question goes for rarities, as in if I meld 3 purples the result will be a purple or better. I haven't noticed anything yet, but I haven't been melding much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gaijin Hunter](http://gaijinhunter.tumblr.com/post/113165119687/mh4u-understanding-the-melding-pot) seems to have something on melding:

> Mystery Melding
>   Makes 1 Mystery Charm.
>   Cost: 1 Frenzy Shard + 3 Pawn/Bishop Talismans
>
> Luminous Melding
>   Makes 1 Shining Charm.
>   Cost: 1 Frenzy Crystal + 3 Knight/Rook Talismans
>
> Ancient Melding
>   Makes 1 Timeworn Charm.
>   Cost: 1 Vile Frenzy Crystal + 3 Queen/King/Dragon Talismans
>
> Fabled Melding
>   Makes 1 Enduring Charm.
>   Cost: 1 Pure Frenzy Crystal + 3 Hero/Legend/Creator Talismans
>
> Halcyon Melding
>   Makes ??? number of ??? Charms.
>   Cost: 1 Frenzy Shard, Crystal, Vile Crystal + 3 Pawn~Unknowable Talismans
>
> Juju Melding
>   Makes ??? number of Timeworn/Enduring Charms.
>   Cost: 3 Vile/3Pure Frenzy Crystals + 3 Pawn~Dragon Talismans.

Based on that information, it looks like melding works on their respective "tiers".  Throw in three of the same tier, get another of that tier.

As for what you get out of it, yeah, that's completely random.  So far as I've experienced, and been able to tell, charms can roll with any skill, at any value.  I've gotten a +10 Cold Res Mystery Charm, while in 3U, I've gotten an Eating +1 on a Rare10 charm.  There's no rhyme or reason, so what you get out of it is a crap shoot.

My gut says that the higher the tier, the better the chance of a higher level skill, like Expert, and the better the chance of a higher value, but I have absolutely nothing to back that up.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that halcyon and juju melding do give better results depending on what you put into it. If you put a lot of high rarity charms into halcyon melding you're more likely to get more high rarity charms back than if you just gave it three rarity 1 ones.

Comment: Also as far as the game is concerned, only the rarity of the charm matters. A rarity 6 Eating+1 charm will give better melding results than a rarity 1 Eating+5, for example. Also some skills are exclusive to higher rarities (such as Handicraft, Evasion, etc), and some are exclusive to low rarities (like Normal S+ and Cold Res).

Comment: @Pyritie You wouldn't happen to have a link or something about that, would you?  I've been unable to find anything to corroborate that information.

Comment: [Here](http://gaijinhunter.tumblr.com/post/113165119687/mh4u-understanding-the-melding-pot) - most of his information is from data miners in japan, he just translates it and puts it into guides. I cna confirm his findings through personal experience.

Comment: @Pyritie That's the link I have in my answer.  I'm not seeing anything on that page about higher rarity charms giving better skills.  That's the part I'm having trouble finding any sort of information on.

Comment: Check the link at the bottom of the post, it's a spreadsheet that shows what skills you can get on what charms. There's also [this](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/wiki/talismans), which lists more than just graven/enduring/distorted/timeworn ones.

Answer (score 1):

Talisman melding is randomized.